# Is this a viable way to calculate the Lyapunov Exponent?

Tags: python, simulation, physics

**Is this a viable way to compute the Lyapunov Exponent for a double pendulum?**

Here is the code for the double pendulum (*You don't have to look at this part, it just returns the angles and angular velocity over time. I just placed it here just in case.* I used the euler method to numerically solve the ODE):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def run_simulation(length_1, length_2, mass_1, mass_2, angle_1, angle_2, angle_1_d, angle_2_d, gravity, dt, num_steps):

    angle_1 = np.deg2rad(angle_1)
    angle_2 = np.deg2rad(angle_2)

    # Angle lists
    angle_1_lst = [angle_1]
    angle_2_lst = [angle_2]

    # Angular velocity lists
    angle_1_d_lst = [angle_1_d]
    angle_2_d_lst = [angle_2_d]

    # Angular acceleration lists
    angle_1_dd_lst = [0]
    angle_2_dd_lst = [0]

    # Trajectory lists (second pendulum)
    p1_x_trace = []
    p1_y_trace = []

    p2_x_trace = []
    p2_y_trace = []

    for _ in range(num_steps):
        angle_1_dd = (-gravity * (2 * mass_1 + mass_2) * np.sin(angle_1) - mass_2 * gravity * np.sin(angle_1 - 2 * angle_2) - 2 * np.sin(angle_1 - angle_2) * mass_2 * (angle_2_d ** 2 * length_2 + angle_1_d ** 2 * length_1 * np.cos(angle_1 - angle_2))) / (length_1 * (2 * mass_1 + mass_2 - mass_2 * np.cos(2 * angle_1 - 2 * angle_2)))
        angle_2_dd = (2 * np.sin(angle_1 - angle_2) * (angle_1_d ** 2 * length_1 * (mass_1 + mass_2) + gravity * (mass_1 + mass_2) * np.cos(angle_1) + angle_2_d ** 2 * length_2 * mass_2 * np.cos(angle_1 - angle_2))) / (length_2 * (2 * mass_1 + mass_2 - mass_2 * np.cos(2 * angle_1 - 2 * angle_2)))

        angle_1_dd_lst.append(angle_1_dd)
        angle_2_dd_lst.append(angle_2_dd)

        # Updating angular velocities
        angle_1_d += angle_1_dd * dt
        angle_2_d += angle_2_dd * dt

        angle_1_d_lst.append(angle_1_d)
        angle_2_d_lst.append(angle_2_d)

        # Updating angles
        angle_1 += angle_1_d * dt
        angle_2 += angle_2_d * dt

        angle_1_lst.append(angle_1)
        angle_2_lst.append(angle_2)

        # Trajectory
        x_1 = length_1 * np.sin(angle_1)
        x_2 = x_1 + length_2 * np.sin(angle_2)
        y_1 = - length_1 * np.cos(angle_1)
        y_2 = y_1 - length_2 * np.cos(angle_2)

        p1_x_trace.append(x_1)
        p1_y_trace.append(y_1)

        p2_x_trace.append(x_2)
        p2_y_trace.append(y_2)

    return angle_1_lst, angle_2_lst, angle_1_d_lst, angle_2_d_lst
```

**And here is how I calculate the Lyapunov Exponent:**

```
epsilon = 0.001 # Initial separation in angle
output_1 = run_simulation(1, 1, 1, 1, 30, 25, 0, 0, 9.81, 0.02, 50)
output_2 = run_simulation(1, 1, 1, 1, 30 + epsilon, 25, 0, 0, 9.81, 0.02, 50)

distance_lst = []
```

...

According to this [study](https://pressbooks.howardcc.edu/jrip2/chapter/a-study-in-chaos/), the separation of the two trajectories is

```
distance = np.sqrt((output_2[0][index] - output_1[0][index])**2 + (output_2[1][index] - output_1[1][index])**2 + (output_2[2][index]*0.02 - output_1[2][index]*0.02)**2 + (output_2[3][index]*0.02 - output_1[3][index]*0.02)**2)
```

But this [study](https://yorke.umd.edu/Yorke_papers_most_cited_and_post2000/1992-04-Wisdom_Shinbrot_AmerJPhys_double_pendulum.pdf) states that the separation is the Euclidean distance of (theta_1, theta_2, theta_dot_1, theta_dot_2) of the angles and angular velocity, which does not include multiplying the velocities by dt (time step). For my code, *I did not use * 0.02 for the angular velocities* (which study is correct? or am I misinterpreting something?).

Then finally,

```
distance_array = np.array(distance_lst)
lyapunov_exponent = np.mean(np.log(distance_array[1:] / distance_array[:-1])) / 0.02
print("Lyapunov Exponent:", lyapunov_exponent)
```

**Does this give the Lyapunov Exponent for the initial conditions?** Thanks in advance. I was unsure which stack exchange I should post this on, so apologies if this post does not belong here.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll get better results on https://math.stackexchange.com